# How to generate random number within a specific range in groovy script

Tags: random, groovy, numbers, generator, ready-api

How do I generate a random number within a specific range in Groovy Script?
I want to generate the number between 10,000 and 90,000

Below are my attempts so far:

1.

```
 Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 10000) +90000
```

2.

```
(int)(10000 + 90000*Math.random())
```

Both of these generate a random number yes, but they are not within the range of 10,00-90,000

Comment: @cfrick Not a duplicate.  that is Java this is using Groovy script

Comment: Minus syntax differences, any Java solution is usually a Groovy solution -- it might not be the shortest one.  Have you tried the most upvoted soltion from that question with Groovy? `java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10000,90000)`

Answer (score 1):

I found my error:  I just needed to switch the 90000 and the 10000 for 1.
Correct code:

```
Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 90000) +10000
```

Comment: This is not correct to your requirements.  You have to do a modul 80k instead.